# Generate an Azure DevOps pipeline "warning" from within a C# unit test

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to cause a C#-based unit test being processed by an Azure DevOps pipeline to generate a warning visible in DevOps?

Reasoning:
We have some time-sensitive unit tests and, unfortunately, our on-prem agent is sometimes slow and can fail these tests, causing a lot of annoyance. I would like to make these tests more lenient but also issue a warning in case the results aren't ideal. Obviously that would need to happen from inside the unit test itself.

I've tried `Console.WriteLine`, `Trace.WriteLine` as well as `Debug.WriteLine`. I've also tried to invoke a PowerShell command

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddArgument("##[warning]warning from unit test").Invoke();
    ps.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddArgument("##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong. PS").Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine("##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong. console");
    Debug.WriteLine("##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong. debug");
    Trace.WriteLine("##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong. trace");
}
```

Unfortunately none of these methods seem to result in a warning "visible" in Azure DevOps after the pipeline has finished.

Comment: Have you tried [`LogIssue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#logissue-log-an-error-or-warning)? [Logging Commands docs on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash). [Specific example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#example-log-an-error): `##vso[task.logissue type=warning]warning from unit test`

Comment: @DM I have now. ;) Unfortunately still nothing. I'm not sure I'm doing it right, however. Do remember this has to be triggered as part of a unit test, not just entered into the pipeline YML.

Comment: That makes sense, hope someone has experience and can help!